# How to minimize query execution time for MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

I am using SQL db and fetching data from two tables using join query. The data fetched is in bulk so execution time is very slow. Any solution for this?

Comment: Google "Indexing on table "

Answer (score 0):

If you create index on the column that you are using for join, will help.
you can use explain to analyze the query.

```
explain select * from ...
```

it will not execute the query it will just analyze it.